# variable_get with prefix

Tags: configuration

It's there a chance to retrieve all key/value, stored in `variable` table, that have a prefix, using `variable_get()`?
e.g: variable_get("prefix_*")

Or I have to use db_select('variable')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not, `variable_get()` is a very simple function that just returns an item in the global `$conf` array, there's no method for searching built in.

You could write your own `variable_select()` function though, and you wouldn't have to go into the database as the entire variable table is loaded into `$conf` at the start of the page build. It might go something like this:

```
function variable_select($prefix) {
  $found = array();

  global $conf;
  foreach ($conf as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
      $found[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  return empty($found) ? FALSE : $found;
}
```

I'm sure that could be improved but it's a start. It's worth noting that this method might match elements from the settings.php file that aren't actually variables in the database as such.

For example, if your prefix is `data`, it's likely you'll see the `$conf['databases']` variable from settings.php in your results. There wouldn't be a way around that without going directly into the db I don't think.

Comment: nice! This is great!